# Perl changing the current package?

Tags: perl

Without using a source-filter, is there a way to change the current running package? I'm trying to accomplish the same thing [oose.pm](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/oose.pm) does, and I'm wondering if I can drop my users in a non-main package.

Answer (score 5):

I think you'll be able to do that by changing `PL_curstash` and `PL_curstname` on the C level.

```
PL_curstash = gv_stashpvs("Some::Package", GV_ADD);
sv_setpvs(PL_curstname, "Some::Package");
```

`PL_curstash` is the stash of the current package during compilation, `PL_curstname` is its name.

**Update:**

I've found this problem kind of interesting and implemented the solution as `Devel::ChangePackage`. Turns out what I initially suggested just works. You can get it either from http://github.com/rafl/devel-changepackage, or from a CPAN mirror near you once they have updated.

Comment: But he's trying to change the _caller's_ package, not his own.

Comment: That's why he should do the above instead of pushing curstash and curstname onto the save stack and making the changes local to the current scope, like the package keyword would do.